# Does one run of Helgrind suffice to guarantee that the given multithreaded implementation is data-race free and deadlock-free?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, parallel-processing, deadlock, valgrind

I have a multithreaded implementation and I would like to test it for deadlocks with Helgrind.
I have run them and have succesfully removed all the data races and deadlocks according to the output Helgrind generated. Now I am wondering how Helgrind detects these errors. Does it generate all the possibilities from the source code and analyse them based on these possibilities or does it only base the result on that particular instance of runtime interleave it saw ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know by experience that the Valgrind tool DRD (which is similar to Helgrind) only finds errors that are encountered during run-time and I'm pretty sure that is also true in the case of Helgrind and any other Valgrind tool.

Also, generating all possible outcomes of an complex program is infeasible, especially when it is threaded.

Comment: Indeed. Helgrind only tries to verify the code that's executed, code that's not executed is not considered. It does report of possible race conditions or lock violations though, even if no damage/corruption occured in a given run.

Comment: This is the classic problem with multi threaded programs which follow the normal design paradigm of shared memory, semaphores, etc. You cannot prove them to be correct by testing alone. Your choices are either i) prove that the program design is itself correct and that the source code implements the design; that's a *lot* of work, or, ii) use a different multi-threaded paradigm like Communicating Sequential Processes. CSP in particular is attractive because it effectively guarantees that if you have the potential for deadlock then you are going to experience it (and thus detect it) in testing